# Error parsing ElasticSearch helm chart when adding lifecycle

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes-helm

I have a camunda/camunda-platform chart deployed on a Kubernetes cluster. I'm trying to set lifecycle policies for indices but am having trouble executing the upgrade command:

```
helm upgrade -f camunda-values.yaml camunda camunda/camunda-platform
```

I get the following error:

```
 Error: UPGRADE FAILED: parse error at (camunda-platform/charts/identity/templates/_helpers.tpl:184): "-"
```

Following is the `camunda-values.yaml` file (note: I've omitted the curl to set the templates for clarity):

```
elasticsearch:
    lifecycle:
        postStart:
            exec:
                command:
                    - bash
                    - -c
                    - |
                      #!/bin/bash
                      # Configure life cycle management
                      ES_URL=http://localhost:9200
                      while [[ "$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' $ES_URL)" != "200" ]]; do sleep 1; done
                      # Add a policy with 30 days delete action
                      TEMPLATE_NAME=index_del_policy
                      curl -X PUT "$ES_URL/_ilm/policy/$TEMPLATE_NAME" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"policy": { "phases": { "delete": { "min_age": "30d", "actions": { "delete": {} } } } } } '
```

Question is, how come I'm getting an error for `identity` when I'm only trying to upgrade `elasticsearch`?

Comment: [github issue of core library](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/issues/492)

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL the error message reported there is different from mine?

Answer (score 1):

Helm version was incompatible. I was using version `3.5.4`. Once I upgraded to `3.11.1` the upgrade ran correctly. `3.11.0` works as well.